# To have Vim Psql's editor

Tags: ubuntu, vim, database, bashrc, psql

I have a Fresh Ubuntu installation.
I have no personal dot-files active.

I run unsuccessfully `\e file.sql` in Psql, when I have the following in my .bashrc, since Nano opens instead of Vim

```
export VISUAL=/usr/bin/vim
export EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim
export PSQL_EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim
```

I run the same command when I have vim in place of PATH/vim in .bashrc for the above three commands.

I get `vim` when I `cat $EDITOR`, for instance.

The problem is in environmental variables likely.
However, I am not sure where.

**How can you have Vim as Psql's editor?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure about `psql`, but if something is goofed up with `$EDITOR` it will probably fall back on the system default as defined through the `/usr/bin/editor` symlink, which is `nano` by default. If you have admin access, try

```
sudo update-alternatives --config editor
```

and select `vim` there. I think programs should still respect `$EDITOR` if it's defined but that will define the fallback. It's the only setting I use and it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the file `~/.selected_editor` or run `select-editor`. Select `/usr/bin/vim-basic` in either case, `/usr/bin/vim` on Ubuntu is a symlink to `/etc/alternatives/vim`, which is a symlink to `/usr/bin/vim.basic`.

Here's the contents of the file for an Ubuntu system's postgres user:

```
postgres@ubuntu904test:~$ cat .selected_editor
# Generated by /usr/bin/select-editor
SELECTED_EDITOR="/usr/bin/vim.basic"
```

Comment: Ah, well if postgres is running as a different user then that would explain the problem with `~/.bashrc` too. Looks like `SELECTED_EDITOR` is yet another way of choosing an editor per-user, with priority between `EDITOR` and the /etc/alternatives links (though my old Ubuntu 8.04 install doesn't honor it). If you want to set the editor system-wide then use the alternatives command I gave below.

Comment: I suppose Debian has real good reasons for things like "selected editor", "update-alternatives", and all those symlinks chasing themselves around the filesystem, but I remember when Unix meant a simple system you could rap your head around...  Now if you'll excuse me, I have to go chase some kids off my lawn. :)

Comment: I run your command `select-editor`. However, Emacs is now my default editor for some unknown reason, although I selected Vim. If I run the command again, the list shows that my default editor is Nano. I run the command with `sudo` unsuccessfully. This suggests me that there is also some file manipulating the editor settings in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the suggestions here and the editor did not change to VIM.  Although the selections were made correctly and the files were updated correctly, the editor continued to be Nano.

sudo update-alternatives --config editor

Edit the file ~/.selected_editor

Finally I deleted the file ~/.selected_editor and executed \ef once again.  Because the .selected_editor file did not exist it allowed this to execute as if this was the first time creating the file. And then I could select "2" for "vim.basic".  The new file was created and VIM became my editor.

postgres=# \ef

Select an editor.  To change later, run 'select-editor'.
  1. /bin/nano        <---- easiest
  2. /usr/bin/vim.basic
  3. /usr/bin/vim.tiny

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Please, consider your thing next time as an comment because it is not answer. Please, see jtb's answer which is the accepted answer here. Please, consider also sending a new thread with a link here.